# Cannot return a sequence of integer values in a xsl:choose

Tags: xslt-2.0

I want to simply return a xsl sequence of integers, but if we have the $value = '2' case, then it does not return a sequence of integers but a String = "4 0". Why is it? Here´s my code:

```
    <xsl:variable name="seq">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$value = '0'"><xsl:value-of select="(4)"/></xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$value = '1'"><xsl:value-of select="(0)"/></xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$value = '2'"><xsl:value-of select="(4,0)"/></xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
```

I´m using Saxon 9.4 PE.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Julian, In case you want your code more readable, you could remove the brackets -- they are not necessary.

Comment: Thank you too, Julian. I didn´t know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sequence is returned with `xsl:sequence`, additionally you would need to use the `as` attribute e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="seq" as="xs:integer*">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$value = '0'"><xsl:sequence select="(4)"/></xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$value = '1'"><xsl:sequence select="(0)"/></xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$value = '2'"><xsl:sequence select="(4,0)"/></xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

Note that XPath 2.0 has an `if` expression so you could use

```
<xsl:variable name="seq" select="if ($value = 0) then 4 else if ($value = 1) then 0 else if ($value = 2) then (4,0) else ()"/>
```

instead of using xsl:choose/xsl:when

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast response, Martin. It worked perfectly! I think I´ll use the choose alternative to set the code more readable. Regards.